# How are Google Apps Script mail quotas calculated?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-apps

The *Current Quotas* table on the [Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) page shows a feature called "**Email read/write (excluding send**)," which is limited to 50,000 / day for G Suite Business customers.

I have several Google Apps Scripts that use **MailApp** to send emails, and today users of my scripts started getting the error: `"Service invoked too many times for one day: email"`

When I ran `MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()` it showed -1, confirming that the quota had been exceeded.

When I checked Google Vault to see how many messages my account had sent between yesterday and today, it showed about 3,294.

When I reached out to G Suite Support to ask about this, they directed me to the [G Suite Admin Email sending limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852) page, which shows that G Suite accounts are limited to sending 2,000 messages per rolling 24-hour period.

3,294 is greater than 2,000, but both are well below 50,000, so I'm wondering what actually counts against the 50,000 quota.

What mail-related operation does "**read/write**" pertain to?

Comment: Have you tried checking about waht was mentioned in [this product forum post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/TvjR5hmRn_s/K0A3sMDoSo8J)?

Comment: I tested `GmailApp.sendEmail()` and it does impact the `MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()` number as well. Also, I've been monitoring the output of `MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()` over the past few days and have found that it's been hovering around 1,300-1,400, but never goes above 1,500,  so it seems that maybe that's showing what is remaining of the "Email recipients per day" quota of 1,500. And sending one test email to two recipients deducts two from the number, so that makes sense. Which leaves me with my original question of how the 50,000 number is relevant, and how I exceeded that.

Answer (score 0):

We also use gsuite and Google script to send lots of mails. And also have lots of questions about quotas. The results of my observation is that limits applied with some lag. I can send over limit mails (some amount), before limitation will apply. Amount is vary and bit unpredictable, but almost always if I do sime pause before sending over limit mails - I got quota errors :(

I can't comment, thats why updating answer. Just try to add few mails into bcc :) and check metrics

Comment: I created a test function which gets the quota with `getMailAppRemainingQuota()`, sends an email with `MailApp` and then gets the quota again, and I've observed no delay - the quota is updated immediately for me.